# How to convert raw to smart pointer when smart pointer is declared in header?

Tags: c++11, pointers, smart-pointers

In our code we are mainly using raw pointers and I would like to introduce smart pointers step by step (i.e. without changing existing functions). We have a factory that returns a pointer to a created object. Several methods in the class make use of this object so the pointer to the created object is declared as a class member.

```
std::unique_ptr<IObject> object;
```

Now, I would like to replace the raw pointer with a smart pointer.

I found out that I can pass a raw pointer to the constructor of a smart pointer (in my case I think unique_ptr is correct one) but because the smart pointer is declared in the header this does not work.
I tried using

```
object = make_unique<IObject>(CreateObject(1));
```

but this gives a compilation error because IObject is abstract.
The only solution I could find is creating a temporary unique_ptr and then using move.

```
//Factory.h
std::unique_ptr<IObject> object; 


//Factory.cpp
IObject* ObjectFactory::CreateObject(int type)
{
   switch( type )
   {
      case 1:
         return new A();
      case 2:
        return new B();
   }
}

//My solution is:
 object = std::move( std::unique_ptr<IObject>(ObjectFactory::CreateObject(1)) );
```

I was wondering if there is a better way than creating a temporary smart pointer and then using move to transfer ownership.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`reset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) member function of unique pointer to set `Iobject` object type to a raw pointer from your factory.

```
//Factory.h
std::unique_ptr<IObject> object; 


//Factory.cpp
IObject* ObjectFactory::CreateObject(int type)
{
   switch( type )
   {
      case 1:
         return new A();
      case 2:
        return new B();
   }
}

//use reset
object.reset(ObjectFactory::CreateObject(1));
```

Here is a minimal working example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Abs {
public:
    virtual ~Abs() = 0;
};
Abs::~Abs(){ std::cout << "called\n"; }
class A: public Abs {};
class B: public Abs {};

Abs* Factory(int type)
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case 1:
            new A();
            break;
        case 2:
            new B();
            break;
    }
}
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Abs> obj;
    obj.reset(Factory(1));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted